# Транспонирование матрицы

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, masm32

Написал программу на Tasm, которая должна транспонировать матрицу, но она почему-то этого не делает...

Если смотреть в дебаггер, то видно что в Al и Ah заносятся одни и те же цифры=> замены никакой не происходит...
Где я допустим косяк?

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    m   equ 3 ;         строки
    n   equ 3 ;         столбци
    a   db  1,2,3
        db  4,5,6
        db  7,8,9
    cnt db ?
    tmp db ?
.code
.486
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,m        ;внешний цикл будет перебирать строки
rows:
    push cx         ;запоминаем текущее значение параметра внешнего цикла в стеке
    mov cx,n        ;внутренний цикл для перебора элементов в каждой строке, т.е. по столбцу
    mov si,0        ;обнуляем номер столбца
colums:
    cmp si,cx;      проверяем является этот элемент элементом главной диагонали
    jz skip         ;Если да, то переходим к следующему элементу
    mov al, byte ptr a[bx][si]
    mov ah, byte ptr a[si][bx]
    mov byte ptr a[bx][si], ah
    mov byte ptr a[si][bx], al
skip:
    inc si      ;переход к следующему столбцу
loop colums
    pop cx
    add bx,n   ;переходим к следующей строке
loop rows
    mov     ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov al, byte ptr a[bx][si]
mov ah, byte ptr a[si][bx]
```

Ещё бы заносились разные :) Это как раз тот самый случай, когда "от перемены мест слагаемых сумма не меняется". Если вы переставили местами `bx` и `si` - код всё равно будет точно таким же :)

```
mov al, byte ptr a[si][bx] ; один адрес
mov ah, byte ptr a[si][bx] ; тот же самый адрес
```

UPD. Вот так и подумалось, что ноги растут из сишных массивов. Здесь же линейный буфер, а в нём адрес нужного нам элемента вычисляется так:

```
offset = row_size * Y + X
```

UPD: По-хорошему, надо бы один раз написать циклы с вычислением линейного адреса каждого элемента в зависимости от обоих индексов. Просто чтобы понять всё это как следует. Но можно воспользоваться и другим подходом, когда вся адресная арифметика понятней станет. Делаем так: используем два указателя. Изначально оба они указывают на начало буфера. Но один будет двигаться по строкам, другой - по столбцам. В результате получаем что-то вроде такого. Уж, sorry, 16-битный TASM насиловать не хочется, тем более что заявлено .486. Ну и разглядывать память под отладчиком тоже неохота, поэтому - нормальный вывод в stdout, связка NASM + libc. Сначала вывод:

```
Before:
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16
After:
   1   5   9  13
   2   6  10  14
   3   7  11  15
   4   8  12  16
```

Ну и код:

```
; ----------------------------------
section .data
matrix      db  1, 2, 3, 4
msize equ   $ - matrix
            db  5, 6, 7, 8
            db  9, 10,11,12
            db  13,14,15,16

format_u    db  '%4u', 0
crlf        db  0Ah, 0
before      db  'Before:', 0Ah, 0
after       db  'After:', 0Ah, 0
; ----------------------------------
section .text
extern printf
global main
; ----------------------------------
main:
    cld
    push before
    call print_matrix
    mov esi, matrix
    mov edi, esi
    mov ecx, msize

loop1:
    push esi
    push edi
    push ecx
    ; в проверке диагоналей тут никакого
    ; смысла нет, обмен и так шустрый
loop2:
    lodsb
    xchg [edi], al
    mov [esi-1], al
    ; указатель esi уже передвинулся по строке (lodsb)
    ; двигаем edi на следующий столбец:
    add edi, msize
    loop loop2

    pop ecx
    pop edi
    pop esi
    add esi, msize+1
    add edi, msize+1
    loop loop1

    push after
    call print_matrix

    xor eax, eax
    ret
; ----------------------------------
print_matrix:
    push dword [esp+4]
    call print_string
    mov ecx, msize
    mov esi, matrix
    xor eax, eax
p1:
    push ecx
    mov ecx, msize
p2:
    lodsb
    push eax
    call print_int
    loop p2
    push crlf
    call print_string
    pop ecx
    loop p1
    ret 4
; ----------------------------------
print_int:
    pushad  ; а чо мелочиться?
    push dword [esp+36]
    push format_u
    call printf
    pop eax ; ну или add esp, 8...
    pop eax
    popad
    ret 4
; ----------------------------------
print_string:
    pushad
    push dword [esp+36]
    call printf
    pop eax
    popad
    ret 4
; ----------------------------------
```

Comment: А как в таком случае мне правильно обратится к разным элементам, что бы в ячейку 2,1 попал элемент 1,2, а в 1,2 элемент 2,1 ? В языках таких как Си достаточно было индексы поменять местами, и эту часть я как раз делал из опыта Си.

Comment: Добавил пояснения.

Comment: Y-строка, X- кол-во столбцов? А как это будет выглядеть в моей программе? Я заранее должен подсчитывать смещение или можно это сделать в момент mov ?

Comment: На языке ассемблера лучше делать несколько не так. В si сделай чтобы адрес одного элемента находился, а в di другого, после обмена к si прибавь 1, а к di размер строки. Тасм вроде достаточно умный ассемблер был, не нужно писать byte ptr... он и сам догадается.

Comment: Для начала я бы посоветовал вычислять адрес на каждом шаге, а когда сам алгоритм будет понят и отлажен - уже заниматься оптимизацией. BTW, ориентироваться на si, di и bx в качестве указателей - прошлый век :) И TASM тут не при чём. Современные процессоры позволяют адресовать память как угодно, хоть так: `mov al,[переменная+edx+ecx]`, что открывает кучу возможностей для "скачков" по адресам в подобных алгоритмах.

Comment: Дополнил рабочим кодом.